# how to use fragment variable from inside child fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have AppleActivity which launches OrangeFragment, which in turns launches BookChildFragment. I have a variable inside OrangeFragment called `Object myObj` that I want to keep using inside BookFragment. (BookFragment only fills a child view inside the layout of OrangeFragment). Does anyone know how to do that? I am using the support library and of course `getChildFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[owe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652133/1037294) is good when you don't need to change your `myObj` from BookFragment. If you want `myObj` to be modifiable then you may use following simple solution:

```
class BookFragment extends Fragment {
    ...

    private void someMethod() {
        OrangeFragment myFragment =
            (OrangeFragment)getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.orangeFragmentId);

        myFragment.setMyObj(null);
    }
}

class OrangeFragment extends Fragment {
    ...

    public Object getMyObj() {
        return myObj;
    }
    public void setMyObj(Object o) {
        myObj = o;
    }
}
```

But if you want more flexible solution, I'd suggest using [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html).

Comment: I just declare it static in the child and set it from the parent. Because I want the exact same instance of the object and not an independent copy.

Comment: That's possible too, but be careful with static fields - do not set them with object which may hold reference to `Activity` (explicitly or implicitly)

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities, but here is one:

Your `Object myObj` should extend from [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) (in the API description you find a typically Implementation of a `Parcelable`).

Now you can transfer `myObj` with a `Bundle` from the OrangeFragment to the BookFragment like this:

```
// create a bundle and add all the data you want to transfer
Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
myBundle.putParcelable("key for myObj", myObj);

// create your BookFragment and set the arguments
BookFragment myBookFragment =  BookFragment.newInstance();
myBookFragment.setArguments(myBundle)

// add or replace the BookFragment inside of OrangeFragment:
FragmentManager myFm = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction myFt = myFm.beginTransaction();
myFt.replace(id, myBookFragment, backStackEntry);
myFt.addToBackStack(name);
myFt.commit();
```

Comment: +1. As I mention, I just declare it static in the child and set it from the parent. Because I want the exact same instance of the object and not an independent copy.